# What is the most accessible charting framework for mobile devices?

Tags: mobile

We are building a finance website and need to chart stocks along an x and y axis and would like to use pinch and zoom interaction to change focus on the charts.

What is the most accessible charting framework for mobile devices?

We are building for all current generation smart phones and require our users to have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are charting stocks you should use http://www.highcharts.com/ which are javascript based and work very well on smart phones and tablets. Specifically look at their highstocks charting library demo http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

They have an excellent API and are very easy to use

Comment: Fantastic, I had searched around webmasters.stackexchange.com some more and found out that highcharts and fusioncharts were the most popular options.

Comment: Highcharts in my opinion are best they have a lot of great features coming out this year. Fusion charts still uses flash which isn't supported by phones tablets etc. I'd go with HC. If you found this answer useful feel free to check it off

Comment: Caution: HighCharts lacks support for WAI-ARIA and is ignored by screen readers.